# What is the best way to use vcpkg to share your project with a friend

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package, cpprest-sdk, vcpkg

I have a project which depends on `cpprestsdk`, `tinyxml2`. I run this project on another computer which has no internet connection, I installed these libraries with vcpkg, I was wondering should I [statically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/01/vcpkg-updates-static-linking-is-now-available/) link these libraries to my solution or use the new [export](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/03/vcpkg-introducing-export-command/) command and create a nuget package and install it on my friend's computer.

**Edit**: I want to say that I don't need to run the generated .exe file, I want to take the whole visual studio solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take the whole VS solution over, the easiest way to get started is to export a NuGet package.

Later on, if you want to update the dependencies or install new ones, you can always transition to a full Vcpkg instance by removing the NuGet package from the solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I didn't get your last sentence, the other computer doesn't even know what vcpkg is :), He tell my just pass me the solution and I want to build.

Answer (score 2):

In 2021 it seems like the best way to do this is to use vcpkg [manifests](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-accelerate-your-team-development-environment-with-binary-caching-and-manifests/#getting-started-with-manifests). Here's an example vcpkg.json:

```
{
    "name": "myproject",
    "version-string": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": [
        "cpprestsdk",
        "tinyxml2"
    ]
}
```

I would just place the vcpkg.json next to the .sln and enable vcpkg manifests. I believe other users of the project have to install vcpkg themselves still, but maybe msbuild can bootstrap it.

Comment: You will soon run into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196821/unable-to-reference-pocosqlite3-using-vcpkg-manifest when your vcpkg install commands specify features like `poco[sqlite3]`