# Unable to reference poco[sqlite3] using vcpkg manifest

Tags: c++, poco-libraries, vcpkg

I'm using vcpkg's manifest feature to reference the dependencies my project has.  I'd like to use Poco's SQLite3 wrapper but I can't figure out how to reference it in the vcpkg.json file.  When I use `poco[sqlite3]`, vcpkg gives me an error stating that I have a mal-formatted reference in my manifest file.  When I use `poco`, Poco is built without the SQLite3 wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the vcpkg [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/manifests.md), I discovered there's a specific syntax to specify that a project requires certain features of a package.

In my case, I had to use the following syntax to specify that my project needed the SQLite3 feature of Poco:

```
{
  "name": "poco",
  "features": ["sqlite3"]
}
```